# storing avatar on user creation

Tags: php, gravatar

I have a random image generated by php (monsterid) and I want to store it on my server upon user registration, but the following gives me an error:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/admin/monsterid/monsterid.php';
$monsterimg = '/admin/monsterid/monsters/'.$timestamp.rand(0,999).'.png';
file_put_contents($monsterimg, file_get_contents($url));
```

Error =

Warning: file_put_contents(/admin/monsterid/monsters/efefef990.png) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/example/public_html/admin/register.php on line 35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the full path here

```
$monsterimg = '/some/path/admin/monsterid/monsters/'.$timestamp.rand(0,999).'.png';
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply - /admin is at the top level though... :\

Comment: @Tim: I still doubt `echo __FILE__` see the output of this. What it says what is the exact path?

Comment: Aha! That's fixed it :) Thanks Shakti - didn't realise you had to go beyond /public_html/

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the path to where the image will be saved. Try using realpath() and dirname()

Comment: How would I use those functions with my code above? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`define('APPLICATION_PATH, realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));`

`$monsterimg = APPLICATION_PATH . '/admin/monsterid/monsters/'.$timestamp.rand(0,999).'.png';`